# CreateQueryBuilder on an association table that has no entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an association table, that has no entity itself, inside an entity. I can do a raw or native query on it but I want to use createQueryBuilder on it. How can I?

Here is the raw query that I want to convert to createQueryBuilder:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT t.* FROM tasks t LEFT JOIN question_tasks qt ON t.id = qt.task_id WHERE qt.question_id = :qtId';

    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata(Task::class, 't');
    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $query->setParameter('qtId', $questionId);

    return $query->getResult();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of impossible use Doctrine ORM without entity. QueryBuilder just converts down to DQL. DQL make queries over your object model.

Says documentation

> You need to think about DQL as a query language for your object model,
>   not for your relational schema.

Check docs here [Doctrine Query Language](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)